# How to allow use of buttons/levers but not repeaters in a region?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to build a redstone tutorial with a few basic builds to help new players on our server, maybe make them interested in redstone. I want them to be able to activate the machines but I don't want them changing the timings/comparator modes etc.

Is this doable using Worldguard flags or something similar?

Using command blocks isn't an option since other admins dislike the spam they create but we need to keep their outputs visible for safety reasons.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade friend, I think this is a great question!

Comment: How is the server configured? Is it bukkit already, or is this flexible. I just want to get a feel for what I'm working with. I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of worldguard, but this feels doable.

Comment: It looks like if you're using worldguard, the blacklist feature is what you want. It has an `on-interact` event that you can set for specific items http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Blacklist

Comment: Simpler idea: Could you put all the redstone except for buttons and levers behind or below glass? Then you just have to put the players into Adventure mode.

Comment: I'm afraid your gonna have to do it the old fashioned way. Maybe make a map to open up command block abilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quite simpler than you think it is. Set the default gamemode to *Adventure* *Mode*. This should make the player able to interact with buttons and levers but not repeaters.

By the way, I am not sure about the lever. I will test this and edit this post later.